# Data list item data bound not working properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to change the button status(Enable or Disable). But it's working for the first control, the second and third control status not changed. Please help me to fix this error.

```
If (e.Item.ItemType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            Dim status As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnstatus"), Button)
            If status IsNot Nothing Then
                If status.Text = "Ready" Then
                    status.Enabled = True
                ElseIf status.Text = "Assigned" Then
                    status.Enabled = False
                Else
                    status.Enabled = False
                End If
            End If

            'do what ever you want to do here using the value of your label
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or _
             e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

//Your Code Here

End If
```